# Fourier series for $f(x)=x^{2m}$ on $[-\pi; \pi]$

Tags: fourier-series

Am I right in the Fourier series on $[-\pi; \pi]$?
$$x^{2m}\sim\frac{\pi^{2m}}{2m+1}+2\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\frac{(-1)^k\pi^{2(m-k-1)}}{n^{2(k+1)}(2m-2k-1)!}\cos\pi n\cos nx$$

Comment: To check this will be a lot of work. Why don't you show your basic calculations; with the integrals, the sines and cosines parts and etc.?

Comment: $b_n=0$, because $\int\limits_{-\pi}^{\pi}x^{2m}\sin nx=0$